# How can I make a model built with small numbers, work with big numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, model, data-analysis, prediction, ensemble-learning

I am making revenue predictions for countries (with millions of people and revenue from millions to billions) with a model made on a city level (most of them with revenue and population in thousands and million). So my result for the country is in million when it should be in billion.

The professor said I can’t just multiply. So what can I do for the model to understand the big data?
Ps: the datasets were minmaxscaled for the model.